# Rewrite URL parameters as directories - like a Wikipedia URL

Tags: url-rewriting, wiki

I'm running a wiki and the URLs look like this:

/wiki/index.php?title=MyTitle

But I'd like it to look like this:

/wiki/MyTitle

How can I do this? I assume this can be done with .htaccess and rewrite rules, and I've looked around on this site and on google but I can't find anything that's really helping me. Right now I've got this, in the .htaccess for the /wiki/ directory.

```
RewriteEngine      on
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=1
RewriteRule        ^(.+)     index\.php\?title=$1     [L]
```

But that just redirects me to /wiki/index.php?title=Index.php and throws a "Redirect loop detected!" error. I'm not sure I really understand how this stuff even works.

Comment: Doesn't the wiki software have built-in capability to handle this?

Comment: It might. I'll have to find out exactly what software it is (I didn't choose or install it) and look up the documentaiton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making complicated rules, just route *all* the traffic to index.php, then handle the "sub-directories" as parameters. I used [this guide](http://www.phpaddiction.com/tags/axial/url-routing-with-php-part-one/) to help me do so. From that site:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
# Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On
#  Rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Put that in your .htaccess file, and the all the traffic will go to index.php. Then write index.php to be essentially a "router" that will load and show other PHP scripts on your server.

You can access the parameter from the PHP by making an array (again, from the linked site):

```
$requestURI = explode(‘/’, $_SERVER[‘REQUEST_URI’]);
```

Then `$requestURI` will be an array of the parameters given, so this:

```
/wiki/MyTitle
```

would be turned into:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => wiki [2] => MyTitle )
```

Comment: This mostly works... but because I use `header("Location: ...");` within my PHP script to redirect to the actual page, it changes what's in the user's address bar. I could prevent that by using `include` rather than a redirect, but that just seems... ugly.

Comment: Why can't you just use your `header()` redirect method with your new URLs? So something like `header("Location: http://www.whatever.com/wiki/MyTitle");`.

Comment: Well, because those URLs don't actually point to anything. I'd like to make it so when you try to access `/wiki/MyTitle`, it gives you the content of `/wiki/index.php?title=MyTitle` -- but without changing the address in your address bar.

Comment: Okay I feel like we're not on the same page here. You want the user to go to "wiki/MyTitle" and stay there (that is, without redirecting), but at the same time, you want the user to see what "index.php?title=MyTitle" would output right? In that case, you would have to change index.php to "understand" the parameters as I've described in the answer. So now, your index.php gets the title parameter like this: `$title = $_GET('title');` or something similar. Get rid of that completely, and now make it something like this: `$title = $requestURI[2]` after the code in the answer above. Does that help?

Comment: The reason that would work, is that `$requestURI[2]` would have the second parameter. So you go to "wiki/MyTitle", apache will route all traffic to index.php because of the rules you put into your .htaccess file. So, `$requestURI[2]` would be "MyTitle". Mess around with it for a while, and let me know if it worked (or didn't).

Comment: Oh, yeah, I get you. This works, but now all the links on the wiki are broken. I'm sure there's a setting in the software that can fix that, though. Thanks for a creative solution, even though I'd still like to do a pure .htaccess hack some day.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Yeah, I'm sure there's a way to do it with just .htaccess rules, but I have no idea how to do that.