# Shortening GET request

Tags: javascript, .htaccess

I have the following URL with a dozen parameters:

> domain.com/search/?fromDate=2020-01-01&toDate=2020-02-01&type=1&subtype=3&author=45

How can I beautify it or at least shorten it using .htaccess or Javascript? I though about using Base64 to encode the data, but I think that the special characters might break something.

Answer (score 1):

it is pretty ok to leave it like that, that is beatifull already :) take look at google search address...

and second thing to note, [base64](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64) increases the length (almost ~33%) not shortening it

Answer (score 0):

You can make another look of your parameters, like dirs:

> domain.com/search/2020-01-01/2020-02-01/1/3/45

Another answer about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303643/rewrite-url-parameters-as-directories-like-a-wikipedia-url) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28970908/htaccess-directory-with-parameter-to-url-parameters).

Answer (score 0):

You can go with session so instead of URL parameters tracking the state, the state will now be tracked in session variables

So when user submits the form that gets submitted to GET url or if user types the ugly long URL http://example.com/search/?fromDate=2020-01-01&toDate=2020-02-01&type=1&subtype=3&author=45, it should hit your `search_ugly()` function
So inside it you would store the KEY=>VALUE pairs in the session

```
public function search_ugly(){
    session_start();
    //retrieve the parameter value from url
    $fromDate = $_GET['fromDate'];
    $toDate = $_GET['toDate'];
    //..
    //.
    $_SESSION["fromDate"] = $fromDate ;
    $_SESSION["toDate"] = $toDate ;
    //..
    //.


    //redirect 
    header("Location: http://example.com/search"); 
}
```

Then redirect user to another URL like `example.com/search` which would trigger the `search_beautiful()` function

```
public function search_beautiful(){
    session_start();
    //retrieve the parameter value from session
    $fromDate = $_SESSION["fromDate"]];
    $toDate = $_SESSION["toDate"];
    //..
    //.

    //create the HTML and send to browser

}
```